# console.log версия bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

Можно ли как то вывести в консоль версию bootstrap?

Comment: а что, внутри файла не написано?

Comment: написано, но мне чот хочется в консоль вывести))

Comment: @Илья емнип придется писать какой-то код для определения. а конкретной функции нет

Comment: а, понял, ну лан )

Answer (score 1):

Например `$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION`:

```js
console.log("Bootstrap " + $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.VERSION);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: о, круто, спасибо